# Trying to use placeholder image in angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

i am trying to use placeholder image in angular2 by binding variable. When i use `"<img src= "http://lorempixel.com/400/200">"` it is displaying image in the browser just fine but when i use the variable for the link, it is not displaying any image.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-tutorials',
    template: `<h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <img [src]="imageLink"/>`
})
export class TutorialsComponent {
    public title = "Tutorials from rahul";
    public imageLink = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize variables inside the constructor as beloe

```
constructor() {
    this.imageLink = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200"

  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/HqOzy7PAH9Q4Qpn9hHU7?p=preview)**

Comment: thank you that solved my problem although i had to change the start field in package.json otherwise it throws error